Problem with Möbius strip made in Unity, mesh technology

Is it possible to remove or hide the line which connects the beginning and the end of the strip?
And please let me know if you need additional information! Thanks!
I tried to search it up and even asked ChatGPT for it but it seems like I'm doing something wrong or anything else

Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a [tour] and see [ask]. Note that StackOverflow is not a code writing service. You need to show some effort to solve the problem, and ask a specific question about your code.
